# Ruby: Convert a string into array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a stupid ruby question

```
def a(ok)
  #...
  ok
end


a("123")
a(["123","456"])
```

How can I make output as array?

```
["123"]
["123","456"]
```

Comment: Output where? At the command line?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method [`Kernel#Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array)

```
def a(ok)
  Array(ok)
end


a("123") # => ["123"]
a(["123","456"]) # => ["123", "456"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#wrap`

```
Array.wrap("123") # => ["123"]
Array.wrap(["123","456"]) # => ["123","456"]
```

Edit:
*This is a rails extension, if you don't use rails, just omit this answer.*

Comment: Can you give the documentation link ?

Comment: Rails extension: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap

Comment: If it is pure ruby, then it cannot work.

Comment: Array#wrap is rails not ruby

Answer (score 0):

```
def a(a)
  [a].flatten
end

a([1,2,3,4])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
a(1)
[1]
a([1,[2]])
[1, 2]
```